# JSON filter array in Python

Tags: python, json, heroku, typeerror

I'm new to Python so I'm trying to guess-and-check the syntax. I have a JSON object that I get back from an API GET:

```
result = requests.get(mbta_url)
data = result.json()
```

That object is huge and I only need a few data points in it. Unfortunately the API doesn't allow me to put params to filter out on the request.

**My question is: How do I filter out this object so it's only returning results where mode.route.route_id = "Orange" AND mode.route.direction.direction_name = "Southbound"**

Here's the data I'm getting back:

```
{
  "stop_id": "place-bbsta",
  "stop_name": "Back Bay",
  "mode": [
    {
      "route_type": "1",
      "mode_name": "Subway",
      "route": [
        {
          "route_id": "Orange",
          "route_name": "Orange Line",
          "direction": [
            {
              "direction_id": "0",
              "direction_name": "Southbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296516",
                  "trip_name": "2:50 pm from Oak Grove to Forest Hills Orange Line",
                  "trip_headsign": "Forest Hills",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469300",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469300",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469359",
                  "pre_away": "283",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "544CBD7E",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.35881",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.05782",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "175",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490468990",
                    "vehicle_label": "1229"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296517",
                  "trip_name": "2:59 pm from Oak Grove to Forest Hills Orange Line",
                  "trip_headsign": "Forest Hills",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469840",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469840",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469726",
                  "pre_away": "650",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "544CB782",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.37376",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.07041",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "120",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469027",
                    "vehicle_label": "1245"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296518",
                  "trip_name": "3:07 pm from Oak Grove to Forest Hills Orange Line",
                  "trip_headsign": "Forest Hills",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470320",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470320",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470307",
                  "pre_away": "1231",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "544CBE8D",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.42462",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.07519",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "200",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469053",
                    "vehicle_label": "1209"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "direction_id": "1",
              "direction_name": "Northbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296558",
                  "trip_name": "2:59 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469120",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469120",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469077",
                  "pre_away": "1",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "544CBD65",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.34571",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.07814",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "40",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469035",
                    "vehicle_label": "1288"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296561",
                  "trip_name": "3:08 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469660",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469660",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469628",
                  "pre_away": "552",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "544CBD69",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.31318",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.10594",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "25",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469061",
                    "vehicle_label": "1263"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296564",
                  "trip_name": "3:16 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470140",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470140",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470085",
                  "pre_away": "1009"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296567",
                  "trip_name": "3:25 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470680",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470680",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470672",
                  "pre_away": "1596"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296570",
                  "trip_name": "3:34 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490471220",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490471220",
                  "pre_dt": "1490471166",
                  "pre_away": "2090"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296541",
                  "trip_name": "3:43 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490471760",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490471760",
                  "pre_dt": "1490471706",
                  "pre_away": "2630"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296545",
                  "trip_name": "3:51 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490472240",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490472240",
                  "pre_dt": "1490472185",
                  "pre_away": "3109"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "route_type": "2",
      "mode_name": "Commuter Rail",
      "route": [
        {
          "route_id": "CR-Franklin",
          "route_name": "Franklin Line",
          "direction": [
            {
              "direction_id": "0",
              "direction_name": "Outbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "CR-Saturday-Fall-16-1711",
                  "trip_name": "1711 (3:20 pm from South Station)",
                  "trip_headsign": "Forge Park/495",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469900",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469900",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469890",
                  "pre_away": "814",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "1827",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.3515701293945",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.0551605224609",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "200",
                    "vehicle_speed": "0",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490468918",
                    "vehicle_label": "1827"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "direction_id": "1",
              "direction_name": "Inbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "CR-Saturday-Fall-16-1710",
                  "trip_name": "1710 (2:35 pm from Forge Park/495)",
                  "trip_headsign": "South Station",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470380",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470380",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470507",
                  "pre_away": "1431",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "1507",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.1975784301758",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.1965026855469",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "7",
                    "vehicle_speed": "0",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490468913",
                    "vehicle_label": "1507"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "route_id": "CR-Needham",
          "route_name": "Needham Line",
          "direction": [
            {
              "direction_id": "0",
              "direction_name": "Outbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "CR-Saturday-Fall-16-1609",
                  "trip_name": "1609 (3:10 pm from South Station)",
                  "trip_headsign": "Needham Heights",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469300",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469300",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469268",
                  "pre_away": "192",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "1531",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.3505516052246",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.055908203125",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "200",
                    "vehicle_speed": "0",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490468911",
                    "vehicle_label": "1531"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "direction_id": "1",
              "direction_name": "Inbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "CR-Saturday-Fall-16-1610",
                  "trip_name": "1610 (4:00 pm from Needham Heights)",
                  "trip_headsign": "South Station",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490474040",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490474040",
                  "pre_dt": "1490474006",
                  "pre_away": "4930"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "route_id": "CR-Providence",
          "route_name": "Providence/Stoughton Line",
          "direction": [
            {
              "direction_id": "1",
              "direction_name": "Inbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "CR-Saturday-Fall-16-1810",
                  "trip_name": "1810 (2:56 pm from Providence)",
                  "trip_headsign": "South Station",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490472120",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490472120",
                  "pre_dt": "1490472187",
                  "pre_away": "3111",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "1707",
                    "vehicle_lat": "41.8979415893555",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.3540573120117",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "86",
                    "vehicle_speed": "0",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490468928",
                    "vehicle_label": "1707"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "route_id": "CR-Worcester",
          "route_name": "Framingham/Worcester Line",
          "direction": [
            {
              "direction_id": "1",
              "direction_name": "Inbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "CR-Saturday-Fall-16-1508",
                  "trip_name": "1508 (2:30 pm from Worcester)",
                  "trip_headsign": "South Station",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490471700",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490471700",
                  "pre_dt": "1490471802",
                  "pre_away": "2726",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "1801",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.2759819030762",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.4203491210938",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "69",
                    "vehicle_speed": "4",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490468935",
                    "vehicle_label": "1801"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "route_type": "3",
      "mode_name": "Bus",
      "route": [
        {
          "route_id": "10",
          "route_name": "10",
          "direction": [
            {
              "direction_id": "0",
              "direction_name": "Outbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "33647996",
                  "trip_name": "3:17 pm from Saint James Ave @ Dartmouth St to City Point Bus Terminal",
                  "trip_headsign": "City Point via South Bay Center",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469540",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469540",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469747",
                  "pre_away": "671"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33647982",
                  "trip_name": "3:39 pm from Saint James Ave @ Dartmouth St to City Point Bus Terminal",
                  "trip_headsign": "City Point via South Bay Center",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470860",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470860",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470858",
                  "pre_away": "1782"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "direction_id": "1",
              "direction_name": "Inbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "33647998",
                  "trip_name": "2:32 pm from City Point Bus Terminal to Saint James Ave @ Dartmouth St",
                  "trip_headsign": "Copley via South Bay Center",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490468880",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490468880",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469438",
                  "pre_away": "362",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "y2160",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.3370819091797",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.0714645385742",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "51",
                    "vehicle_speed": "0",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469034",
                    "vehicle_label": "2160"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33647979",
                  "trip_name": "2:55 pm from City Point Bus Terminal to Saint James Ave @ Dartmouth St",
                  "trip_headsign": "Copley via South Bay Center",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470260",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470260",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470085",
                  "pre_away": "1009",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "y1779",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.3294982910156",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.061149597168",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "144",
                    "vehicle_speed": "0",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469009",
                    "vehicle_label": "1779"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33648025",
                  "trip_name": "3:17 pm from City Point Bus Terminal to Saint James Ave @ Dartmouth St",
                  "trip_headsign": "Copley via South Bay Center",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490471580",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490471580",
                  "pre_dt": "1490471507",
                  "pre_away": "2431"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33648010",
                  "trip_name": "3:39 pm from City Point Bus Terminal to Saint James Ave @ Dartmouth St",
                  "trip_headsign": "Copley via South Bay Center",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490472900",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490472900",
                  "pre_dt": "1490472729",
                  "pre_away": "3653"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "route_id": "39",
          "route_name": "39",
          "direction": [
            {
              "direction_id": "0",
              "direction_name": "Outbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "33788263",
                  "trip_name": "3:15 pm from Back Bay Station to Forest Hills Station",
                  "trip_headsign": "Forest Hills",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469300",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469300",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469300",
                  "pre_away": "224"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33788273",
                  "trip_name": "3:25 pm from Back Bay Station to Forest Hills Station",
                  "trip_headsign": "Forest Hills",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469900",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469900",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469900",
                  "pre_away": "824"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33788283",
                  "trip_name": "3:35 pm from Back Bay Station to Forest Hills Station",
                  "trip_headsign": "Forest Hills",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470500",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470500",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470882",
                  "pre_away": "1806"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "direction_id": "1",
              "direction_name": "Inbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "33788252",
                  "trip_name": "2:35 pm from Forest Hills Station to Back Bay Station",
                  "trip_headsign": "Back Bay",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490468940",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490468940",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469286",
                  "pre_away": "210",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "y1269",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.3499755859375",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.0776748657227",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "72",
                    "vehicle_speed": "0",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469032",
                    "vehicle_label": "1269"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33788262",
                  "trip_name": "2:45 pm from Forest Hills Station to Back Bay Station",
                  "trip_headsign": "Back Bay",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469540",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469540",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469850",
                  "pre_away": "774",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "y1251",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.3383369445801",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.09375",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "59",
                    "vehicle_speed": "0",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490468986",
                    "vehicle_label": "1251"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33788272",
                  "trip_name": "2:55 pm from Forest Hills Station to Back Bay Station",
                  "trip_headsign": "Back Bay",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470080",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470080",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470882",
                  "pre_away": "1806",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "y1271",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.3093566894531",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.115592956543",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "0",
                    "vehicle_speed": "0",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469016",
                    "vehicle_label": "1271"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33788282",
                  "trip_name": "3:05 pm from Forest Hills Station to Back Bay Station",
                  "trip_headsign": "Back Bay",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470620",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470620",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470966",
                  "pre_away": "1890",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "y1260",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.3032569885254",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.1146392822266",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "351",
                    "vehicle_speed": "0",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490468980",
                    "vehicle_label": "1260"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33788292",
                  "trip_name": "3:15 pm from Forest Hills Station to Back Bay Station",
                  "trip_headsign": "Back Bay",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490471220",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490471220",
                  "pre_dt": "1490471891",
                  "pre_away": "2815"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33788218",
                  "trip_name": "3:25 pm from Forest Hills Station to Back Bay Station",
                  "trip_headsign": "Back Bay",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490471820",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490471820",
                  "pre_dt": "1490472018",
                  "pre_away": "2942"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33788230",
                  "trip_name": "3:35 pm from Forest Hills Station to Back Bay Station",
                  "trip_headsign": "Back Bay",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490472420",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490472420",
                  "pre_dt": "1490472675",
                  "pre_away": "3599"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

I have tried to cut down the object with this but it errors out in the function:

```
#results
x = json.loads(data)
routes = x['mode'][0]['route_type']
```

Here is the error I'm getting the Heroku logs:

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: Because it's passing through to a webhook result, I can't seem to debug it. It breaks the result when I try to do a `data.get('Mode')`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: *"it errors out"* - be more specific.

Comment: Updated with the error. I'm not trying to shortcut here, I'm just lost in the beginning of exploring Python...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider treating the json as a collection of nested dictionaries/lists. Hence, iterate through the *mode* list and conditionally select only *route_names* (dict key) whose value is *Orange Line*. Then, append such content to a growing *newdata* dictionary.

Below uses `OrderedDict()` in order to maintain the key order of original since dictionaries by default do not maintain key order. However, lower dictionary items may re-order even with this approach.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

# receive api request...into 'data' object...

# INITIALIZE NEW FILTERED DICTIONARY (RETAINING TOP LEVEL ITEMS)
newdata = OrderedDict({k:v for k,v in data.items() if k in ['stop_id', 'stop_name']})
newdata['mode'] = []

# ITERATE CONDITIONALLY KEEPING NEEDED SECTIONS
for i in data['mode']:
    if i['route'][0]['route_name'] == 'Orange Line':
        newdata['mode'].append(OrderedDict(i))    

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open('Output.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(newdata, indent=2))
```

**Output**

```
{
  "stop_id": "place-bbsta",
  "stop_name": "Back Bay",
  "mode": [
    {
      "route_type": "1",
      "mode_name": "Subway",
      "route": [
        {
          "route_id": "Orange",
          "route_name": "Orange Line",
          "direction": [
            {
              "direction_id": "0",
              "direction_name": "Southbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296516",
                  "trip_name": "2:50 pm from Oak Grove to Forest Hills Orange Line",
                  "trip_headsign": "Forest Hills",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469300",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469300",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469359",
                  "pre_away": "283",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "544CBD7E",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.35881",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.05782",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "175",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490468990",
                    "vehicle_label": "1229"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296517",
                  "trip_name": "2:59 pm from Oak Grove to Forest Hills Orange Line",
                  "trip_headsign": "Forest Hills",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469840",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469840",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469726",
                  "pre_away": "650",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "544CB782",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.37376",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.07041",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "120",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469027",
                    "vehicle_label": "1245"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296518",
                  "trip_name": "3:07 pm from Oak Grove to Forest Hills Orange Line",
                  "trip_headsign": "Forest Hills",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470320",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470320",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470307",
                  "pre_away": "1231",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "544CBE8D",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.42462",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.07519",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "200",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469053",
                    "vehicle_label": "1209"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "direction_id": "1",
              "direction_name": "Northbound",
              "trip": [
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296558",
                  "trip_name": "2:59 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469120",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469120",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469077",
                  "pre_away": "1",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "544CBD65",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.34571",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.07814",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "40",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469035",
                    "vehicle_label": "1288"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296561",
                  "trip_name": "3:08 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490469660",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490469660",
                  "pre_dt": "1490469628",
                  "pre_away": "552",
                  "vehicle": {
                    "vehicle_id": "544CBD69",
                    "vehicle_lat": "42.31318",
                    "vehicle_lon": "-71.10594",
                    "vehicle_bearing": "25",
                    "vehicle_timestamp": "1490469061",
                    "vehicle_label": "1263"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296564",
                  "trip_name": "3:16 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470140",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470140",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470085",
                  "pre_away": "1009"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296567",
                  "trip_name": "3:25 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490470680",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490470680",
                  "pre_dt": "1490470672",
                  "pre_away": "1596"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296570",
                  "trip_name": "3:34 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490471220",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490471220",
                  "pre_dt": "1490471166",
                  "pre_away": "2090"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296541",
                  "trip_name": "3:43 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490471760",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490471760",
                  "pre_dt": "1490471706",
                  "pre_away": "2630"
                },
                {
                  "trip_id": "33296545",
                  "trip_name": "3:51 pm from Forest Hills Orange Line to Oak Grove",
                  "trip_headsign": "Oak Grove",
                  "sch_arr_dt": "1490472240",
                  "sch_dep_dt": "1490472240",
                  "pre_dt": "1490472185",
                  "pre_away": "3109"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For all *sch_arr_dt* values, keep conditionally walking down the nested dict/list collection:

```
sch_arr_dt = []

for i in data['mode']:
    if i['route'][0]['route_name'] == 'Orange Line':        
        if i['route'][0]['direction'][0]['direction_name'] == 'Southbound':
            for s in i['route'][0]['direction'][0]['trip']:
                sch_arr_dt.append(s['sch_arr_dt'])

print(sch_arr_dt)
# ['1490469300', '1490469840', '1490470320']
```

*Naturally, as an avid rider of Chicago's Orange Line, I had to answer this question! =)*

Comment: Thank you so much. This is incredibly helpful. This is a little out of scope from my original question, but what I'd like to do now is take all the Southbound trips and get an array of `sch_arr_dt`. How would you iterate through that part of the tree?

Comment: See extension where you continue down the collection conditionally.